# Kibana status page load number meaning

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

What does these **Load** numbers mean in kibana status page?

[image: kibana]

Answer (score 0):

Ok its actulally node stats **load_1m load_5m load_15m**

```
 GET _cat/nodes?v
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-nodes.html